# How to see the flowtype for a specific version of React

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

The React flow definitions seem to change between versions

eg. for React version 15.6.1, PureComponent has the definition

```
declare class React$PureComponent<DefaultProps, Props, State> extends React$Component<DefaultProps, Props, State> {
  // TODO: Due to bugs in Flow's handling of React.createClass, some fields
  // already declared in the base class need to be redeclared below. Ideally
  // they should simply be inherited.

  static defaultProps: $Abstract<DefaultProps>;
  props: Props;
  state: $Abstract<State>;
}
```

but the [current definition](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/157fd35685fe89482b961bd3b11a6ada84365cf2/lib/react.js#L89) is

```
declare class React$PureComponent<Props, State = void>
  extends React$Component<Props, State> {
  // TODO: Due to bugs in Flow's handling of React.createClass, some fields
  // already declared in the base class need to be redeclared below. Ideally
  // they should simply be inherited.

  props: Props;
  state: State;
}
```

the change was in https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.53.0

The question is how to get the flow definations for my version of React

> flow-typed install react@15.6.1

does not work as well

another question is, my `package.json` has a dependency on flow-bin so where are these changes coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow version is not specifically tied to a React version. The changes to the type of `Component` and `PureComponent` are improvements in the way Flow types them in Flow v0.53, regardless of what version of React you use.

If you want the old types, any React and Flow < 0.53 will work. If you want the new version, any React and Flow >= 0.53 will work.

There's a rundown of why this was changed and what you need to do in your code in this blog post on Flow 0.53: https://medium.com/flow-type/even-better-support-for-react-in-flow-25b0a3485627

Comment: so upgrading Flow changes how my React code is typed, even though React itself is not updated ? seems weird!  

"The flow version is not specifically tied to a React version"  

Also, and this maybe a separate question, but my `.flowconfig` file does not have a definition for React under [lib](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/libs/), so how is it getting picked up ?  

And is there any other library like React whose defination is vendored with flowtype ?

Comment: Yeah, I agree this isn't very intuitive. But the typing rules for React are pretty complex and some of them require extra features or special handling in the core of Flow's type system. If you read that blog post, it has a codemod that can do the minor syntax changes for Flow in v0.53, so hopefully it isn't too big a pain. And no, Flow has internal types for the DOM, BOM, core JS objects, node, and React, but that's it.